# Calling rss feed with plsql

Tags: web-services, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to call a webservice from plsql. I have the following code (which works):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WEBSERVICE AS
    v_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
    v_xml := XMLTYPE(UTL_HTTP.REQUEST(URL => 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/Quote?symbol=AAPL'));
    FOR x IN (SELECT
        EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(p), '/Data/Status/text()') AS title
    FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(v_xml, '/QuoteApiModel/Data'))) p)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x.title);
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

But this code does not work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WEBSERVICE AS
    v_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
    v_xml := XMLTYPE(UTL_HTTP.REQUEST(URL => 'http://xkcd.com/rss.xml'));
    FOR x IN (SELECT
        EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(p), 'item/title/text()') AS title
    FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(v_xml, '/rss/channel/item'))) p)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x.title);
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Connecting to the database oracle.
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00007: unexpected end-of-file encountered
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 310
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WEBSERVICE", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 2
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database oracle.
```

The difference I noticed is that the xkcd rss feed has an xml header and the other one doesn't. What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You right, error occured because of presence of XML header.

Workaround is to use [`XMLParse(document ...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#CHDBCGCI) to parse XML:

```
select xmlparse(document UTL_HTTP.REQUEST(URL => 'http://xkcd.com/rss.xml')) 
into v_xml 
from dual;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc6e2/13) with results from xkcd.com.

Notice, that according to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#i998070) `HTTP_UTIL.Request` function returns only first 2000 bytes of server response, so you can get incomplete XML with such request.

**Update**

More elegant way to extract values from XML is to use [`XMLTable()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions240.htm) function with [XQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_xquery.htm) :

```
FOR x IN (

  select title
  from 
    XMLTable(
      'for $i in $p/rss/channel/item/title return $i'
      passing 
        XMLParse(document UTL_HTTP.REQUEST(URL => '...')) as "p"
      columns 
        title varchar2(4000) path '//title'
    )

)  
LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x.title);
END LOOP;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc6e2/15)

At least, this method allows you to create more flexible options for different sources of RSS.